# Two way data binding between component and provider (for global vars) in Ionic 3 with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, ionic3

I've the following code:

`app.html`:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-content [ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(#'+menuColor1+', #'+menuColor2+')'}">
        ...
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage" swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

`app.components.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { GlobalsProvider } from '../providers/globals/globals';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = TabsPage;

  menuColor1: string = GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_1;
  menuColor2: string = GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_2;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
        GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_1 = "f00";
        GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_2 = "ff0";

        console.log(GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_1); // f00
        console.log(this.menuColor1); // 000 (expected: f00)

        console.log(GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_2); // ff0
        console.log(this.menuColor2); // 000 (expected: ff0)
    });

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

`globals.ts`:

```
export const GlobalsProvider = {
    MENU_COLOR_1: "000",
    MENU_COLOR_2: "000",
}
```

I want to do a two way data binding between the `app.component.ts` and `globals.ts`, for each time that vars `MENU_COLOR_1` and `MENU_COLOR_2` are changed, update too in `menuColor1` and `menuColor2` values (I will update `MENU_COLOR_1` and `MENU_COLOR_2` from another componenets too in the future and I want that `menuColor1` and `menuColor2` receive these changes).

It is possible?

Comment: Every time I see a JavaScript class with only static members, I die a little bit inside.

Comment: Why not use it, @AluanHaddad? What's the downside?

Comment: It's just cruft and nonsense. We have _objects_ in this language. Why are you creating a _function_ that never gets called and shoving things into it? Just `export const GlobalsProvider = {prop: initialValue};`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Actually I had not even thought about this approach, I already updated the code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are mutable and are passed by reference. Primitive types, like `string` are not, therefore they are not changing as you hope. So what you should do, is to work with objects:

```
menuColor1 = GlobalsProvider;
menuColor2 = GlobalsProvider;

ngOnInit() {
  GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_1 = "f00";
  GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_2 = "ff0";

  console.log(GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_1); // f00
  console.log(this.menuColor1.MENU_COLOR_1); 

  console.log(GlobalsProvider.MENU_COLOR_2); // ff0
  console.log(this.menuColor2.MENU_COLOR_2); 
}
```

But be very careful with this, since as mentioned, objects are passed by reference, so sometimes you might not want this behavior.